# New table doesn't created

Tags: magento2, database

My install InstallSchema.php:

> app/code/Aty/TestTask/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Aty\TestTask\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;

class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $setup->startSetup();
        $conn = $setup->getConnection();
        $tableName = $setup->getTable('added_sku');
        if ($conn->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            $table = $conn->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['identity'=>true,'unsigned'=>true,'nullable'=>false,'primary'=>true]
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'sku',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable'=>false,'default'=>'']
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'count',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    255,
                    ['nullbale'=>false,'default'=>'']
                )
                ->setOption('charset','utf8');
            $conn->createTable($table);
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and  `php bin/magento setup:db-schema:upgrade` created strange file. Like : `.nfs0000000000d41f0f0000000b.`

> module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Aty_TestTask" setup_version="1.0.1" active="true">
    </module>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Aty_TestTask" schema_version="1.0.1" setup_version="1.0.1"/>
</config>
```

Go to your database, `setup` table, remove this record:

```
Aty_TestTask    1.0.1   1.0.1
```

And try again.

Answer (score 1):

just re-try to replace your code with below code

> module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Aty_TestTask" setup_version="1.0.2" active="true">
    </module>
</config>
```

> InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Aty\TestTask\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{

    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup,ModuleContextInterface $context){
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();

        // Get tutorial_simplenews table
        $tableName = $installer->getTable('added_sku');
        // Check if the table already exists
        if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create tutorial_simplenews table
            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['identity'=>true,'unsigned'=>true,'nullable'=>false,'primary'=>true]
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'sku',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable'=>false,'default'=>'']
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'count',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    255,
                    ['nullbale'=>false,'default'=>'']
                )
                ->setOption('charset','utf8')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

after that run this command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code to add a new table in database.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/registration.php**

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_Custom',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_Custom" setup_version="1.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/Setup/InstallSchema.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Anshu\Custom\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface as Db;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $tablename = 'anshu_custom';
        $table = $setup->getConnection()->newTable($setup->getTable($tablename));

        $table->addColumn('id', Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, [
            'primary' => true,
            'identity' => true,
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
        ]); 
        $table->addColumn('name', Table::TYPE_TEXT, 124, [
            'nullable' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('description', Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, [
            'nullable' => false,
            'default' => '',
        ]);
        $table->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName($tablename, ['name'], Db::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE),
            ['name'],
            ['type' => Db::INDEX_TYPE_UNIQUE]
        );
        $table->addIndex(
            $setup->getIdxName($tablename, ['description'], Db::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT),
            ['description'],
            ['type' => Db::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT]
        );
        $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
// NOTE :: createTable builds sql with "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"
```

And then run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

This is sample code, modify it according to your requirement.